# Chat application using socket.io over https

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, socket.io

I've been working on a chat application using node.js and socket.io . I'm trying to run it over https .I'm a newbie in node.js and socket.io so please bear with me . Every help will be highly appreciated. I follow the instructions from here : http://kaworu.jpn.org/javascript/node.js%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8BHTTPS%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8A%E6%96%B9

but i get this error :

```
GET https://mydomain.link:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1502934404775-5 net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

here is the code

server.js

```
    var https = require('https');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var ssl_server_key = 'server_key.pem';
    var ssl_server_crt = 'server_crt.pem';
    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;



    var options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(ssl_server_key),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(ssl_server_crt)
    };

    https.createServer(options, function (req,res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.end("Hello, world\n");
    }).listen(port);
```

clientside (chatnew.js)

```
    $(function(){
      var socket = io.connect('https://mydomain.link:3000');
    });
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I believe your certificate is not trusted on the machine you are using to test.

Comment: @logikal hi, can you link me to a site where i can do that ?

Comment: You can either request a certificate from a trusted CA, or you can generate a CA and trust it on your computer - you will need to google, or ask another question because it is out of scope for this question. It also depends on what client you are using - if you are just using `curl` you can just supply they `-k` argument to ignore an insecure certificate

Comment: Find where `server_crt.pem` is on your computer and use the appropriate certificate manager to trust it on your machine - You will probably want to google `How to trust a certificate on <my_os_here>`

Comment: @logikal thank you so much !

Comment: Your code shows no server-side socket.io server.